# How to catch the redirected urls with urllib2 in python

Tags: python, url, redirect, urllib2, httplib

I am using urllib2 module to read a html page and below is my code

**code.py**

```
import urllib2, httplib

httplib.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1  
request = urllib2.Request("http://www.vodafone.in/Pages/tuesdayoffers_che.aspx")
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(request)
print f.url
```

**Result**

```
'http://www.vodafone.in/pages/tuesdayoffers_che.aspx?cid=che'
```

When i had given the above url in browser it is redirected to `http://www.vodafone.in/pages/home_che.aspx?cid=che`, but here from the above code i am getting the same given url

So finally how to catch the redirected urls using urrlib2 and read the data from it becuase
i had a number of urls which will be redirected to some other urls , finally my intension is to catch the redirected url and read the data from the catched url, so how to achieve this in python using `urllib2 and httplib`

Comment: Look at: http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html

Comment: i tried those but does n't works for me so approached SO, can u provide code according to above scenario ?

Comment: I guess that page uses javascript based redirection.

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions aren't necessary. The site is redirecting by JavaScript, however, a 302 status code is still returned. You can verify this by:

```
url = 'http://www.vodafone.in/Pages/tuesdayoffers_che.aspx'
file_pointer = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print file_pointer.getcode()
```

When a 302 status code is returned, there is a `Location` header in the response headers. You can view this by:

```
url = 'http://www.vodafone.in/Pages/tuesdayoffers_che.aspx'
file_pointer = urllib2.urlopen(url)
print file_pointer.info()
```

Record the `Location` url. It will be the page you were redirected to.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, @Sp is right, this web page is redirected by javascript. The following is the page source.

```
<script>document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"3;url=/pages/home_che.aspx\">");</script>
```

One approach is using a regular expression to extract the redirection location. like `url\=([a-z_./]*)`

```
>>> import re
>>> p = re.compile(r'url\=([a-z_./]*)')
>>> p.findall(r'''<script>document.write("<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\"content=\"3;url=/pages/home_che.aspx\">");</script>''')
['/pages/home_che.aspx']
```